# How to call custom methods of React component while doing unit testing. I am using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am using react with typescript. Can anyone tell me how to call the custom methods which is written in component inside unit testing.

I tried `shallow` and `mount` but I am not able to call custom methods.

```
import React  from 'react';
import {
  Theme,
  withStyles,
  createStyles,
} from '@material-ui/core';

export interface IFileUploadProps{}
export interface IFileUploadState {}

const styles = (theme: Theme) => {
  return createStyles({
    root: {
      paddingTop: theme.spacing(2),
      paddingBottom: theme.spacing(2),
      width: '100%',
      backgroundColor: 'inherit',
    },
    input: {
      display: 'none',
    },
    padding24: {
      paddingLeft: theme.spacing(3),
      paddingRight: theme.spacing(3),
    },
  });
};

class FileUpload extends React.Component<IFileUploadProps, IFileUploadState> {

    validateImage = () => {
      console.log('validate image');
    }

    render() {
      return <div>file upload</div>;
    }
  }

export default withStyles(styles)(FileUpload);
```

I need to do something like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import FileUpload from './FileUpload';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });   
describe('FileUpload', () => {
  test('should call validateImage method correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<FileUpload ></FileUpload>);
    wrapper.instance()['validateImage']();
  });
});
```

Here I am getting error.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'validateImage' of null

**This error occurs when i export file using "export default withStyles(styles)(FileUpload);" 
When i use export default FileUpload it is working fine.**

Comment: are you talking about mocking?

Comment: Updated the description hope u understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. For example:

`FileUpload.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';

interface IFileUploadProps {}
interface IFileUploadState {}

export class FileUpload extends React.Component<IFileUploadProps, IFileUploadState> {
  validateImage() {
    console.log('validate image');
  }

  render() {
    return <div>file upload</div>;
  }
}
```

`FileUpload.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { FileUpload } from './FileUpload';

describe('FileUpload', () => {
  test('should call validateImage method correctly', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const wrapper = shallow(<FileUpload></FileUpload>);
    expect(wrapper.text()).toBe('file upload');
    // @ts-ignore
    // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
    wrapper.instance()['validateImage']();
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('validate image');
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58642342/FileUpload.spec.tsx
  FileUpload
    ✓ should call validateImage method correctly (14ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    validate image

----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File            |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files       |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 FileUpload.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.487s, estimated 9s
```

**Update 1**

You should disable `strict: true` in your `tsconfig.json` file. Or, use `// @ts-ignore` to skip the static type check of tsc.

**Update 2**

Since you use HOC - the `withStyles` high order function, so you need use [.dive([options]) => ShallowWrapper](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html) method of `enzyme` to get the  shallow wrapper of `FileUpload` component.

`FileUpload.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Theme, withStyles, createStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

interface IFileUploadProps {}
interface IFileUploadState {}

const styles = (theme: Theme) => {
  return createStyles({
    root: {
      paddingTop: theme.spacing(2),
      paddingBottom: theme.spacing(2),
      width: '100%',
      backgroundColor: 'inherit'
    },
    input: {
      display: 'none'
    },
    padding24: {
      paddingLeft: theme.spacing(3),
      paddingRight: theme.spacing(3)
    }
  });
};

class FileUpload extends React.Component<IFileUploadProps, IFileUploadState> {
  validateImage() {
    console.log('validate image');
  }

  render() {
    return <div>file upload</div>;
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(FileUpload);
```

`FileUpload.spec.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import FileUpload from './FileUpload';

describe('FileUpload', () => {
  test('should call validateImage method correctly', () => {
    const logSpy = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const wrapper = shallow(<FileUpload></FileUpload>);
    expect(wrapper.dive().text()).toBe('file upload');
    // @ts-ignore
    // tslint:disable-next-line: no-string-literal
    wrapper
      .dive()
      .instance()
      ['validateImage']();
    expect(logSpy).toBeCalledWith('validate image');
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58642342/FileUpload.spec.tsx
  FileUpload
    ✓ should call validateImage method correctly (31ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    validate image

----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File            |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files       |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 FileUpload.tsx |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.517s, estimated 12s
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58642342

Comment: Thanks for code. But when I try I am getting error. I have attached screenshot as an answer

Comment: @Gowthamr.cs Update answer, please check.

Comment: Thanks, in this code it is working. But in my project code it is giving error while running test case .

"Cannot read property 'validateImage' of null" . Don't know what is the issue :(

Comment: Please check my Updated description . We are using "export default withStyles(styles)(FileUpload)". This is giving error in unit test.

Comment: @Gowthamr.cs Update answer. Please check **Update 2** part